# Touchpad isn't working on anything but windows

Tags: dual-boot, mouse, touchpad, synaptics

I know some people posted issues on this but mine is a little different...just to let you know, it's not a hardware issue because it works in windows but the touchpad doesn't work in Ubuntu and i even tried booting the live cd. i also booted Kali Linux to see if it would work with no luck and i even tried booting Manjaro Linux which is arch based just to see if it was an issue with Ubuntu and it still doesn't work. it seems to not work with Linux in general but it works with windows and I'm a computer tech and usually I have an idea on how to fix the problem but with this issue I don't. I can hook a mouse up to it and it works fine but the touchpad and even the left and right mouse buttons on the touchpad doesn't work either. I even tried hitting FN + F5 which that enables/disables the touchpad on my laptop with no luck. (My laptop model is a Toshiba Satellite S55-B5280). In the system settings, the touchpad is enabled btw. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Go into a terminal and type in 'xinput list', see if a touchpad is listed. if not, it hasn't been detected. If it is there, however, there may be some configuring to do.

Comment: I typed it in and it's listed.. This is what it says exactly.. "ETPS/2 Elantech TouchPad           id=12    [slave   pointer   (2)]" do you know what i have to do from here or can you point me in the right direction? Thanks for the help!